# Need Shell script for getting the file name created

Tags: bash, shell

I am writing a script to get output if a specific file is created successfully or failed.

Example: In a path /x/y/z/ everyday a file with name abc.out_timestamp will be created.

The script that i am working needs check if the file is created today or not and show the output accordingly.

```
Path : /x/y/z have the below files
abc.out0114181500
abc.out0115181600
abd.out0116182100
```

script to be run:

```
#!/bin/bash
TODAY=$(date +%m%d%y)

cd /x/y/z

if [ -f abc.out_$TODAY ]
then
      echo "$file creation successful"
else
     echo "$file creation not successful"
fi
```

output received: file creation not successful (though a file is created today) 
expected output:  file creation successful

How can i correct this, can anyone please let me know how i can the output as file creation successful.

Thanks

Comment: In the filename `abc.out0114181500` the MMDDYY is `011418` but what is the `1500`? Why does the script insert an underscore `_` between the `out` and the date? Finally, it would make a lot more sense if the date was YYMMDD instead.

Comment: 1500 is the time HHMM, and the format we are using for timestamp is MMDDYYHHMM. The uderscore _ , I found it in google and tried it that way to fetch the file that is created today but it is not working. Instead if iam looking for the file name along with the timestamp i am getting the output as expected, but i cannot use this method as the timestamp keeps changing everyday. @Jim Garrison

Answer (score 0):

You're 98% of the way there

```
#!/bin/bash
TODAY=$(date +%m%d%y)

cd /x/y/z

if [ -f abc.out${TODAY}???? ]
then
     echo "$file creation successful"
else
     echo "$file creation not successful"
fi
```

The pattern `abc.out${TODAY}????` matches the filename with today's date followed by 4 more characters (and without the underscore, which was spurious).

If you want more validation, use

```
if [ -f abc.out${TODAY}[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9] ]
```

I hope the `abd.` was a typo and it's really `abc.`  However, if it could be `abc` or `abd` you can handle that with

```
if [ -f ab[cd].out${TODAY}[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9] ]
```

Comment: If you need to find out which file name(s) exactly matched the wildcard, use it as the pattern in a `for` loop. If the loop only executes once and the file it loops doesn't exist, there were no matches. (This is the default behavior out of the box; you can also use e.g. `nullglob` to make it loop zero times if the wildcard doesn't match anything.)

Comment: Hi @tripleee can you please give me an example of the scenario that you mentioned. Thanks in advance

Comment: It's not hard to find examples. `for file in "abc.out${TODAY}"[0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9]; do test -f "$file" || continue; echo found "$file", now do something with it; done`

Comment: Also i would like to get the filename in the output (example: file created successful filename: abc.out0117180900) so that i will know it is getting the recent most file created, for the scenario that i posted.